# How do I make the borders on a HTML/CSS percent chart thinner?

Tags: jquery, html, css, codepen

I'm trying to use the % charts from this tutorial here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XERbXQ

```
<div class="graphsWrapper">
        <section class="sect">
            <div>
                <div class="box-piesite">
                    <header>
                        <h1>Awwwards Pies</h1>
                        <p>Let's take a peak at them simple pie's</p>
                    </header>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="design">
                            <div class="piesite" id="pie_0" data-pie="2.04"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="usability">
                            <div class="piesite" id="pie_2" data-pie="5.00"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="creativity">
                            <div class="piesite" id="pie_1" data-pie="2.00"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="content">
                            <div class="piesite" id="pie_3" data-pie="6.43"></div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

I can get it working without issue, the only thing is that I want the progress border to be much thinner but every css style I change to try to fix it does't affect it. I've googled searched it and maybe I've used the wrong terminology but I can't find any answers. Any help is much appreciated!

An Idea of what I'm trying to replicated is midway down this page:

http://preview.themeforest.net/item/splendid-responsive-multipurpose-theme/full_screen_preview/13537450

Comment: Can't see any pies on that preview page - unless you mean the circles at the bottom - they're images.

Comment: Oh shoot, it won't let me link to the page, if you go to homepages > homepage version 3 you'll see them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to ask is: what's causing the width of the circle.  The obvious reaction would be `border-width` - but changing that just moves them about, so it's not that.

The next thing would be to take out parts of the css until you no longer get a hollow circle, then determine what causes that to create the circle border.

Giving:

```
.piesite:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:.05em;
  left:.05em;
  width:.9em;
  height:.9em;
  background:$color-lightgrey;
  border-radius:0.5em;
  z-index:1
}
```

Adjust the `top:` `left:` `width:` and `height:` accordingly and in relation to each other.

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLNYyy